# Coded UI typing "@d" opens file menu

Tags: coded-ui-tests

during playback I run into an issue:

```
uIEMailAdresseEdit.Text = this.BasisWeb_0_Anmeldung_Zugangsdaten_SetzenParams.UIEMailAdresseEditText;
```

In my scenario I have users with an email address like this "user@data.com". If the "@d" is typed in, the file menu of Internet Explorer is opened (german Version: alt + d is the same shortcut as alt + f in english Version).
My testrun crashes at this point. Of course I could use other email addresses, but this is not an option for me.
I'm using Windows 7 64bit and Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Update 3.

Any ideas?
Best regards
benny

Answer (score 0):

Benny,

Setting the text does enter the string in character by character but I do find it mysterious that you're having this issue. I've entered hundreds of random email addresses in this way and never had keyboard shortcuts pop up. I'd try four things:

- Before changing the text of the control object, make sure that you've set the focus on the object.
- Ensure that the parameter text you're trying to send to the control object is a literal string.
- Try using "Keyboard.SendKeys" directly. To me this seems counterintuitive, in my opinion you should only be seeing this issue when **using** Keyboard.SendKeys, not when setting the text directly.
- Do some substring Voodoo. IE send the substring before the '@', then the '@', then the remainder of the string. This is ugly but 100% should work.

If you end up resolving the issue, please let us know!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I solved it by supressing the menu bar via registry. For the Moment this is working for me.

Comment: I will try your suggestions later :)